# Перебор объекта 2 массивов Handlebars + node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars

Не могу решить задачу у меня есть JSON объект c 2 свойствами которые имею массивы.

```
"gallery": [{
       "images": ["firstImg.jpg", "secondImg.jpg", "threeImg"],
       "description": ["someFirstTxt", "SecondTxt", "ThreeTxt"]
}]
```

По структуре создано промежуточное ПО к которому я обращаюсь к JSON документу

```
const placesJSON = require("./lib/places.json");

    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    const places = placesJSON;
    if(!res.locals.placesArray) res.locals.placesArray = {};
    res.locals.placesArray = places;
    next();
});
```

И на html странице идет участок на котором рендерятся и перебераються эти 2 массива

```
{{#each placesArray.gallery}}
    <img src="somePath/{{images}}">
    <p>{{description}}</p>
 {{/each}}
```

Но в чём проблема, как можно сделать правильно чтобы была по очередность, так чтобы сперва шел

```
<div>
     <img src="path/firstPhoto" alt="">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>

     <img src="path/secondPhoto" alt="">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet: часть 2</p>
     <img src="path/thirdPhoto" alt="">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet: часть 3</p>
     И так далее....
</div>
```

А то вообще не как не могу решить эту задачку, пытался перебрать эти 2 массива и используя `resultArray.push(arr[i], arr1[i])` к примеру, но не могу потом использовать отдельно свойства для фото`{{images}}` и для параграфа`{{description}}`, а полная путаница происходит ибо фотом будет и 10 а текста около 4 параграфов и на оборот.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Не могу решить задачу у меня есть JSON объект c 2 свойствами которые имею массивы.

Ваш `JSON`

```
{"gallery": [{
       "images": ["firstImg.jpg", "secondImg.jpg", "threeImg"],
       "description": ["someFirstTxt", "SecondTxt", "ThreeTxt"]
}]}
```

Вот так получается:

```
{{#each gallery}}
{{#each images }}
    <img src="somePath/{{this}}">
    <p>{{lookup ../description @index}}</p>
  {{/each}}
 {{/each}}
```

- `{{lookup <ref_array> @index }}` - динамическое обращение к прараметрам.

---

> А то вообще не как не могу решить эту задачку, пытался перебрать эти 2 массива и используя `resultArray.push(arr[i], arr1[i])` к примеру, но не могу потом использовать отдельно свойства для фото`{{images}}` и для параграфа`{{description}}`, а полная путаница происходит ибо фотом будет и 10 а текста около 4 параграфов и на оборот.

Объектов в галреи может быть много, конечно такой вид `JSON` более логичен, у каждой картины свое описание и т.д.

```
{
    "gallery": [{
        "objects": [{
                "image": "firstImg.jpg",
                "description": "someFirstTxt"
            },
            {
                "image": "secondImg.jpg",
                "description": "SecondTxt"
            },
            {
                "image": "threeImg",
                "description": "ThreeTxt"
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

И тогда:

```
{{#gallery}}
{{#each objects}}

    <img src="somePath/{{image}}">
    <p>{{description}}</p>

 {{/each}}
{{/gallery}}
```

---

Браузерный пример:

```js
// Сам темплейт
var template = document.querySelector('#handlebars-demo').innerHTML;


var templateScript = Handlebars.compile(template);
//----------------------------------------------------------------
// JSON
var context = {
  "gallery": [{
    "objects": [{
        "image": "//picsum.photos/200/300",
        "description": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas."
      },
      {
        "image": "//picsum.photos/200/301",
        "description": "Vestibulum tortor quam,feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper."
      },
      {
        "image": "//picsum.photos/200/302",
        "description": "Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo."
      }
    ]
  }]
};
//----------------------------------------------------------------

var html = templateScript(context);
// Добавление в body
document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

```css
img {
  border: 2px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.11/handlebars.runtime.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.11/handlebars.min.js"></script>

<!-------- Пример -------->
<script id="handlebars-demo" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#gallery}} {{#each objects}}

  <img src="{{image}}" />
  <p>{{description}}</p>

  {{/each}} {{/gallery}}
</script>
<div class="app"></div>
```

---

Проверить можно без браузера [ТУТ](http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/)

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за пример и за разъяснение в помощи решения данного вопроса :) Ибо пока что изучаю данные технологии. И как-то упустил этот момент в документации, спасибо большое, вопрос закрыт!